# Store SymPy solve() results in a useful form

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, jupyter-lab

I wrote a for-loop to solve for a bunch of angles. I have all the results stored in a NumPy array of dictionaries. But I want all the answers in degrees (not radians) and rounded. It is basic but I am having difficulties getting the result I want. There are only three inputs to my equations and one does not have a solution. Each input has two solutions (two pairs of angles).
My code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
#Enable LaTex display
smp.init_printing()

L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5=smp.symbols('L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,theta5')
def lengths():
    L1=17
    L2=9
    L3=12
    L4=6
    L5=14
    return np.array([L1,L2,L3,L4,L5])
def thetas():
    theta1=np.repeat(np.radians(15),repeats=3)
    theta3=np.array([np.radians(30),np.radians(195),np.radians(330)])
    theta4=np.array([np.radians(100),np.radians(200),np.radians(300)])
    return np.array([theta1,theta3,theta4])
def position_vectors():
    R1=np.array([L1*smp.cos(theta1),L1*smp.sin(theta1)])
    R2=np.array([L2*smp.cos(theta2),L2*smp.sin(theta2)])
    R3=np.array([L3*smp.cos(theta3),L3*smp.sin(theta3)])
    R4=np.array([L4*smp.cos(theta4),L4*smp.sin(theta4)])
    R5=np.array([L5*smp.cos(theta5),L5*smp.sin(theta5)])
    return smp.Matrix([R1,R2,R3,R4,R5])
def loop_equations():
    R=position_vectors()
    i_comps=smp.Eq(R[1,0]+R[2,0]+R[3,0]-R[0,0]-R[4,0],0)
    j_comps=smp.Eq(R[1,1]+R[2,1]+R[3,1]-R[0,1]-R[4,1],0)
    return [i_comps,j_comps]
print('Equations necessary to perform position analysis:')
display(loop_equations()[0])
display(loop_equations()[1])

Solution_matrix=np.zeros((len(thetas()),2),dtype=object)
L1,L2,L3,L4,L5=lengths()
for k in range(len(thetas())):
    theta1,theta3,theta4=thetas()[:,k]
    i_comps_subs=loop_equations()[0]
    j_comps_subs=loop_equations()[1]
    Solution=smp.solve([i_comps_subs,j_comps_subs],[theta2,theta5],dict=True)
    if Solution==[]:
        Solution_matrix[k]='No solution'
    else:
        Solution_matrix[k]=Solution
print(Solution_matrix)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Equations necessary to perform position analysis:
−1cos(1)+2cos(2)+3cos(3)+4cos(4)−5cos(5)=0
 
−1sin(1)+2sin(2)+3sin(3)+4sin(4)−5sin(5)=0
 
[[{theta2: 0.801807835029103, theta5: 1.62880348609314}
  {theta2: 3.85043163709124, theta5: 3.02343598602721}]
 ['No solution' 'No solution']
 [{theta2: 0.309428353211201, theta5: -1.16362912461926}
  {theta2: 2.44857937919009, theta5: -2.36154845015903}]]
```

Comment: apply the transformation `rad` -> `deg`... it's just a proportionality relationship (`* 180/pi`)

Comment: maybe smt like `Solution_matrix[Solution_matrix != 'No solution'] * 180 / np.pi`

Comment: @Cards I can't do that for values in a dictionary.

Comment: "useful" depends on where it's going after and how it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

To convert all values the following could be used:

```
if Solution==[]:
    Solution_matrix[k]='No solution'
else:
    for dic in Solution:
        dic.update((key, round(degrees(value))) for key, value in dic.items())
    Solution_matrix[k]=Solution

#output
[[{theta2: 46, theta5: 93} {theta2: 221, theta5: 173}]
 ['No solution' 'No solution']
 [{theta2: 18, theta5: -67} {theta2: 140, theta5: -135}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Store SymPy `solve()` results in a useful form

is not meaningful, because you haven't specified what the storage is used *for* or by *what*. You might not actually want to store anything at all, if all you care about is printing. But one way or the other, you should not be storing the literal string `No solution`; that's a printing detail that should be deferred until the printing stage.

> I want all the answers in degrees (not radians) and rounded

This is also a printing detail that should be deferred and not stored.

More generally, this code doesn't make very good use of Sympy. All of the terms and equations should be left symbolic (and not evaluated as floating-point until that's absolutely necessary). Unfortunately, a purely symbolic solution through Sympy is very slow for this problem, so it's probably only practical to solve numerically.

```py
from typing import Callable

import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
from sympy.matrices.dense import matrix_multiply_elementwise


def get_lengths() -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array((17, 9, 12, 6, 14))


def get_theta() -> smp.Matrix:
    theta2, theta5 = smp.symbols('theta2,theta5', real=True)
    return smp.pi/180 * smp.Matrix((
        (15, theta2,  30, 100, theta5),
        (15, theta2, 195, 200, theta5),
        (15, theta2, 330, 300, theta5),
    ))


def get_position_vectors(L: np.ndarray, theta: smp.Matrix) -> tuple[smp.Matrix, smp.Matrix]:
    def get_R(fun: Callable) -> smp.Matrix:
        return matrix_multiply_elementwise(
            theta.applyfunc(fun), L_tall
        )

    L_tall = smp.Matrix(np.broadcast_to(L, theta.shape))
    return get_R(smp.cos), get_R(smp.sin)


def get_loop_equations(Ri: smp.Matrix, Rj: smp.Matrix) -> smp.Matrix:
    factors = smp.Matrix((-1, 1, 1, 1, -1))
    lhs = smp.Matrix((
        (Ri*factors).T,
        (Rj*factors).T,
    ))
    return lhs.T


def print_solutions(solutions: list[list[dict[smp.Symbol, float]]]) -> None:
    for i, row in enumerate(solutions, start=1):
        print(f'Problem {i}:')
        if row:
            for solution in row:
                print('  ' + ', '.join(
                    f'{smp.pretty(v)}={val:6.1f}°'
                    for v, val in solution.items()
                ))
        else:
            print('  No solution')


def main() -> None:
    smp.init_printing()

    L = get_lengths()
    theta = get_theta()
    Ri, Rj = get_position_vectors(L, theta)
    lhs = get_loop_equations(Ri, Rj)

    print('Equations necessary to perform position analysis:')
    print('lhs_i =')
    smp.pprint(lhs[:, 0])
    print('lhs_j =')
    smp.pprint(lhs[:, 1])

    solutions = []

    for i in range(lhs.shape[0]):
        # Without floating-point evaluation, solve() is extremely slow
        lhs_row = lhs[i, :].evalf()
        solution = smp.solve(lhs_row, lhs_row.free_symbols, dict=True)
        solutions.append(solution)

    print_solutions(solutions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Equations necessary to perform position analysis:
lhs_i =
⎡     ⎛π⋅θ₂⎞         ⎛π⋅θ₅⎞   17⋅√6   17⋅√2        ⎛4⋅π⎞       ⎤
⎢9⋅cos⎜────⎟ - 14⋅cos⎜────⎟ - ───── - ───── - 6⋅cos⎜───⎟ + 6⋅√3⎥
⎢     ⎝180 ⎠         ⎝180 ⎠     4       4          ⎝ 9 ⎠       ⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢         ⎛π⋅θ₂⎞         ⎛π⋅θ₅⎞   29⋅√6   29⋅√2        ⎛π⎞     ⎥
⎢    9⋅cos⎜────⎟ - 14⋅cos⎜────⎟ - ───── - ───── - 6⋅cos⎜─⎟     ⎥
⎢         ⎝180 ⎠         ⎝180 ⎠     4       4          ⎝9⎠     ⎥
⎢                                                              ⎥
⎢         ⎛π⋅θ₂⎞         ⎛π⋅θ₅⎞   17⋅√6   17⋅√2                ⎥
⎢    9⋅cos⎜────⎟ - 14⋅cos⎜────⎟ - ───── - ───── + 3 + 6⋅√3     ⎥
⎣         ⎝180 ⎠         ⎝180 ⎠     4       4                  ⎦
lhs_j =
⎡     ⎛π⋅θ₂⎞         ⎛π⋅θ₅⎞   17⋅√6        ⎛4⋅π⎞       17⋅√2⎤
⎢9⋅sin⎜────⎟ - 14⋅sin⎜────⎟ - ───── + 6⋅sin⎜───⎟ + 6 + ─────⎥
⎢     ⎝180 ⎠         ⎝180 ⎠     4          ⎝ 9 ⎠         4  ⎥
⎢                                                           ⎥
⎢        ⎛π⋅θ₂⎞         ⎛π⋅θ₅⎞   29⋅√6        ⎛π⎞   29⋅√2   ⎥
⎢   9⋅sin⎜────⎟ - 14⋅sin⎜────⎟ - ───── - 6⋅sin⎜─⎟ + ─────   ⎥
⎢        ⎝180 ⎠         ⎝180 ⎠     4          ⎝9⎠     4     ⎥
⎢                                                           ⎥
⎢        ⎛π⋅θ₂⎞         ⎛π⋅θ₅⎞   17⋅√6              17⋅√2   ⎥
⎢   9⋅sin⎜────⎟ - 14⋅sin⎜────⎟ - ───── - 6 - 3⋅√3 + ─────   ⎥
⎣        ⎝180 ⎠         ⎝180 ⎠     4                  4     ⎦
Problem 1:
  θ₂=  45.9°, θ₅=  93.3°
  θ₂= 220.6°, θ₅= 173.2°
Problem 2:
  No solution
Problem 3:
  θ₂=  17.7°, θ₅= -66.7°
  θ₂= 140.3°, θ₅=-135.3°
```

### Exponential form

This problem is well-represented as root-finding on a single exponential-form complex expression, and fairly simplifies a lot of the matrix math from the previous approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import sympy as smp
from sympy.matrices.dense import matrix_multiply_elementwise


def get_lengths() -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array((17, 9, 12, 6, 14))


def get_theta() -> smp.Matrix:
    theta2, theta5 = smp.symbols('theta2,theta5', real=True)
    return smp.pi/180 * smp.Matrix((
        (15, theta2,  30, 100, theta5),
        (15, theta2, 195, 200, theta5),
        (15, theta2, 330, 300, theta5),
    ))


def get_position_vectors(L: np.ndarray, theta: smp.Matrix) -> smp.Matrix:
    from sympy import I

    def eI(x: smp.Expr) -> smp.Expr:
        return smp.exp(I*x)

    L_tall = smp.Matrix(np.broadcast_to(L, theta.shape))
    return matrix_multiply_elementwise(L_tall, theta.applyfunc(eI))


def get_loop_equations(R: smp.Matrix) -> smp.Matrix:
    return R * smp.Matrix((-1, 1, 1, 1, -1))


def print_solutions(solutions: list[list[dict[smp.Symbol, float]]]) -> None:
    for i, row in enumerate(solutions, start=1):
        print(f'Problem {i}:')
        if row:
            for solution in row:
                print('  ' + ', '.join(
                    f'{smp.pretty(v)}={val:6.1f}°'
                    for v, val in solution.items()
                ))
        else:
            print('  No solution')


def main() -> None:
    smp.init_printing()

    L = get_lengths()
    theta = get_theta()
    R = get_position_vectors(L, theta)
    lhs = get_loop_equations(R)

    print('Equations necessary to perform position analysis:')
    print('lhs =')
    smp.pprint(lhs)

    solutions = []
    for lhs_row in lhs:
        # Without floating-point evaluation, solve() is extremely slow
        solution = smp.solve(lhs_row.evalf(), lhs_row.free_symbols, dict=True)
        solutions.append(solution)

    print_solutions(solutions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Equations necessary to perform position analysis:
lhs =
⎡      ⅈ⋅π⋅θ₂       ⅈ⋅π⋅θ₅       ⅈ⋅π      5⋅ⅈ⋅π       ⅈ⋅π    ⎤
⎢      ──────       ──────       ───      ─────       ───    ⎥
⎢       180          180          12        9          6     ⎥
⎢   9⋅ℯ       - 14⋅ℯ       - 17⋅ℯ    + 6⋅ℯ      + 12⋅ℯ       ⎥
⎢                                                            ⎥
⎢   ⅈ⋅π⋅θ₂       ⅈ⋅π⋅θ₅       ⅈ⋅π       -11⋅ⅈ⋅π       -8⋅ⅈ⋅π ⎥
⎢   ──────       ──────       ───       ────────      ───────⎥
⎢    180          180          12          12            9   ⎥
⎢9⋅ℯ       - 14⋅ℯ       - 17⋅ℯ    + 12⋅ℯ         + 6⋅ℯ       ⎥
⎢                                                            ⎥
⎢     ⅈ⋅π⋅θ₂       ⅈ⋅π⋅θ₅       -ⅈ⋅π       -ⅈ⋅π        ⅈ⋅π   ⎥
⎢     ──────       ──────       ─────      ─────       ───   ⎥
⎢      180          180           6          3          12   ⎥
⎣  9⋅ℯ       - 14⋅ℯ       + 12⋅ℯ      + 6⋅ℯ      - 17⋅ℯ      ⎦
Problem 1:
  θ₂=  45.9°, θ₅=  93.3°
  θ₂= 220.6°, θ₅= 173.2°
Problem 2:
  No solution
Problem 3:
  θ₂=  17.7°, θ₅= -66.7°
  θ₂= 140.3°, θ₅=-135.3°
```